# Please ,How to get the date component from the column TimeStamp as index ? so I want it without the time

Tags: python

How to get the date component from the column  TimeStamp as an index? so I want it without the time. thanks
for example, I have dataframe with a column like this

2017-02-04 08:04:00

so I want only this  2017-02-04

Comment: just use split()

Answer (score 0):

```
dateString = '2017-02-04 08:04:00'
dateStringArray = dateString.split()
print dateStringArray[0]
```